# Returning three IQueryable lists in a single ActionResult to show in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET, MVC, C# and programming in general, so I have been doing some personal projects and various tutorials to learn.

I've hit a problem that I am not sure which way to turn for a solution or if indeed I have gone down the right road. The code below best explains what I am trying to do. I know the ViewModel isn't right, but I think it shows what I am trying to do. (allTransactions and the vars for the various days have been snipped for brevity).

```
var yesterdaystransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == yesterday);
var todaystransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == today);
var tomorrowstransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == tomorrow);
var ViewModel = yesterdaystransactions.ToList() + todaystransactions.ToList() + tomorrowstransactions.ToList();
```

The intention is to show an At-a-glance screen that has a list of yesterday's transactions at the top, today's in the middle, and tomorrow's at the bottom.

I tried @Html.Partial at first, but of course that just showed me the same list three times. I also tried some if statements in the View but something didn't feel right about doing it this way as I was repeating myself.

Can anyone offer some advice about what areas I should read about and how I should approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track - you need a View Model. That's a class that is just used to contain all the data you need to render your View.

In this case, something like this would do:

```
public class MyActionViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Transaction> YesterdaysTransactions { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Transaction> TodaysTransactions { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Transaction> TomorrowsTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller, you populate an instance of this class:

```
var vm = new MyActionViewModel
  {
    YesterdaysTransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == yesterday),
    TodaysTransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == today),
    TomorrowsTransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == tomorrow),
  }
;

return View( vm );
```

The last thing you have to do is tell your View about the View Model you're going to give it:

```
@model MyActionViewModel
```

Then you can access the data like this

```
@Model.TodaysTransactions
```

Comment: Thanks for helping things to click in to place on this. Awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using AJAX, then you shoul use JsonResult

```
return Json(new {
  yesterdaystransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == yesterday).ToList(),
  todaystransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == today).ToList(),
  tomorrowstransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == tomorrow).ToList()
});
```

if you are trying to render view then create ViewModel

```
var model = new MyViewModel {
  Yesterdaystransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == yesterday).ToList(),
  Todaystransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == today).ToList(),
  Tomorrowstransactions = allTransactions.Where(t => t.WhenItHappensId == tomorrow).ToList()
};
return View("_SomePartialView", model);
```

Comment: I am not using AJAX at the moment as I thought it would steepen my learning curve for now. I am going to bookmark your answer and come back to it when I do try to add AJAX to my knowledge.